# How to properly use login system

Tags: python

I have found a login function, but how do I check that the login has been completed? This is my code:

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your password")  
    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines(): # Read the lines
        login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
           print("Correct credentials!")
           return True
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
    return False

while login() == False:
    login()
```

Comment: It will only work in command line. Is it the way you want to see it?

Comment: Does the actual file has a username and password per line with a space in between? Because this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your password")  
    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines(): # Read the lines
        login_info = line.split() # Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
           print("Correct credentials!")
           return True
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
    return False

while login() == False:
    login()
else:
    print("Your in")
```

use an else statement in your while loop

Comment: When I get the password wrong I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last): / File "python", line 12, in <module> / File "python", line 6, in login / IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: this is your own code thats complaining `if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:` i'm suspecting that you either have empty lines in your text file, or just lines without spaces, never the less there is a line which when split does not contain 2 things (space sepperated).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

First thing:

> ***Do not never ever save user credentials as plain text!!!!....***

Read about password storage on the internet and try your best, but avoid to do the above.

---

Secondly:

There is a problem in your executing loop. The loop can only be exited on every second call of `login`, because the function will be executed at the condition and once in the body. The second execution does not have any effect on your program, because the return value of `login` will be generated and forgotten right away. I would suggest to just "do nothing" inside the loop and be a little bit more pythonic on the condition.

```
while not login() : pass
```

---

**Conclusion**

*Your code actually does what you intended*, as far as I have understood your question.